# jquery dynamically added divs firing a function more than once

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I have a page where I add divs dynamically. All Divs are draggable and resizable. If I click on the div, it should become editable. Here is my test code.

http://jsfiddle.net/hqhqb5ut/1/

Click on the `first Div` to see this.

But If I click to drag the div, only dragging should happen. This works fine if there is only one div. But If I add more divs, only the last one behaves correctly. The previous ones become editable, even if I drag.

I checked the console, and it seems like the function is being called multiple times because there are more than one div with same class.

How can I solve this?

UPDATE 1:
I have the dynamic part figured out. I saw the SO question, that was suggested as duplicate. But here is a specific problem. If you click on the "Add div", and try to drag the divs, only the **LAST ADDED DIV** can be dragged. offcourse, there is a function to check if it is being dragged, but that fails due to multiple divs.

http://jsfiddle.net/hqhqb5ut/1/

Comment: @arun-p-johny I saw the question, but that is not solving the issue. Can you take a look at the updated fiddle? and see if you can drag the divs after you add more divs? only the last added div can be dragged.

Comment: I re-opened your question, but please make sure to put here all the required info. Don't just link to it. Thanks and good luck.

Comment: @aVC I'm able to drag all the added div's.... can you check it again

Comment: @ArunPJohny It is draggable the first time. But if you click inside a div once, and click outside, then it wont be draggable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use event delegation and your code should work fine:

```
$('#documentMain').on('mousedown', '.dv1', function() { ..... });
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/hqhqb5ut/2/)

As you can see in the demo, the change makes the added divs both editable and draggable multiple times.

Comment: not for me. If you add a div, click on the <p> inside this newly added Div, Click outside again, and then try to drag this Div

Comment: What browser are you on? I am on Chrome and everything works great!

Comment: Chromium on ubuntu14. The first div is good. I agree. Can you repeat the effect for a newly added div?

Comment: Quite likely you're trying to drug it via the editable area; you've got to grab on non-editable area. The cursor has to be a pointer.

Comment: Exactly. Which is why I have a function validateClick() that checks this to see if I am dragging, or clicking to edit. :(

Comment: Checking on chrome on a mac, same issue.

Comment: I think I know why this is happening. You may not be keeping good track of dragging. One sec.

Comment: Sure. Appreciate it. I noted that the first original div has no issues. only the newly added ones show the trouble.

Comment: Can't seem to catch it now.

Comment: Really? It still shows the same issue to me. I am looking at the demo fiddle you posted. http://jsfiddle.net/hqhqb5ut/2/

Comment: I just noticed that in the new divs, the Textareas are not being reset to <p> on blur. I made few quick changes,  http://jsfiddle.net/hqhqb5ut/3/ this seems to do the job. I am not sure if I am missing anything

Comment: Yap, glad you nailed :) Looks great! Sorry I could not help much.